# MQTT.JS connect function prepends "ws://localhost" to host URL

Tags: mqtt, mqtt.js

I'm using MQTT.JS in a React component. For some reason when I try to connect to my HiveMQ host the connect function prepends the URL with "localhost"

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

First I called the connect function with an option object which contained a "host" key. The result was that the connect function ignored the host key and connected to ws://localhost directly

```js
const mqttConnect = (mqttOptions) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mqttOptions, null, 4))
    setClient(mqtt.connect( mqttOptions ))
}
```

The second thing I tried was to call the function naming the host explicitly by including it as the first argument. That resulted in the connect function prepending the host URL with ws://localhost

```js
const mqttConnect = (mqttOptions) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mqttOptions, null, 4))
    setClient(mqtt.connect( mqttOptions.host, mqttOptions) )
}
```

This is what the options object looks like:

**mqttOptions: {
"host": "58xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0c.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud",
"port": "8884",
"clientId": "icodefusion",
"username": "icode",
"password": "password",
"protocol": "MQTT"
}**

I included a snapshot of the error
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/3495/UEAqem.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The `protocol` key should come from the output of `URL.parse()` so should contain `wss` not `MQTT` for a MQTT over websockets.

I believe you have miss read the doc which mentions `protocolId`

Comment: I will add a parsing function, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the config you are showing, this should be the correct way to call the `connect` function:

```js
const mqttConnect = ({host, clientId, username, password}) => {
  setClient(mqtt.connect(`wss://${host}`, {clientId, username, password}))
}
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#api for details.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, the results were a little better but for some reason the connect function still wants to connect to 'localhost'. Here is a snapshot of the state of my component/client and the options followed by the error: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/9287/CoNmBA.jpg